# URL.revokeObjectURL doesn't remove blobs from "Sources" panel and from chrome://blob-internals/

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, fileapi, createobjecturl, revokeobjecturl

The problem is basically what the title says. The minimal example to demonstrate it is below.

This function accepts a `File` object as an argument from `<input type='file' />` field. It creates a URL and revokes it 5 seconds later.

```
const compress = (file) => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  console.log('url created');
  setTimeout(() => {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
    console.log("url revoked");
  }, 5000);
};
```

The blob appears in the Sources panel and I would expect it to disappear (to be garbage collected) after 5 seconds, but it doesn't.

What could be the reason it's not garbage collected?

[image]

It's also not removed from `chrome://blob-internals/`

[image]

As far as I understand it's a memory leak. How can I fix it?